# Display Nagative Number in Debit and Credit Forumla

Tags: excel, formula

I used below accounting calculation

```
| DEBIT_OB    | CREDIT_OB | DEBIT      | CREDIT     | NETDEBIT  | NETCREDIT |
|-------------|-----------|------------|------------|-----------|-----------|
| 134054.00   | 0.00      | 5195.00    | 29.50      | 139219.50 | 0.00      |
| 2297.50     | 0.00      | 89.00      | 29.50      | 2357.00   | 0.00      |
| -1831227.00 | 0.00      | 7808826.00 | 6248961.00 | 0.00      | 271362.00 |
| 37761.00    | 0.00      | 0.00       | 0.00       | 37761.00  | 0.00      |
```

NET DEBIT FORMULA: `= IF((((A6+C6)-(B6+D6))>0), ((A6+C6)-(B6+D6)), 0)`

NET CREDIT FORMULA: `= IF((((B6+D6)-(A6+C6))>0), ((B6+D6)-(A6+C6)), 0)`

Net Credit amount shown: `271362/-`

I want Net Debit amount: `-271362/-` (Negative Number)

Comment: Net Credit should be `271362` (missing the 6 in your value)?

Comment: Yes Sorry 271362 its correc

Comment: What I'm asking is the amount of net credit in NET debit ( -) come as a sum

Answer (score 0):

Just make the formula negative by adding in a "-"

= IF((((A6+C6)-(B6+D6))>0), -((A6+C6)-(B6+D6)), 0)

Comment: Net Credit amount shown: 271362/-

I want Net Debit amount: -271362/- (Negative Number) answer is net debit -271362/-

Comment: Maybe `=-E6` where E6 contains `271362`.  Otherwise how do you want NetDebit to equal `-271362` using a _139219, 2357 and 37761_ as starting numbers?

Comment: What I'm asking is the amount of net credit in NET debit ( -) come as a sum

Comment: @MurugaVel - Look at the example I gave you.  In the "ELSE" portion of the formula, there is a "-" in front of "((A6+C6)-(B6+D6))".  This will return "-271362".